# I/Choreographer: Skipped 439 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, arraylist

> i want to connect   the bT Module to my android mobile. But when i run my code this error is come I/Choreographer: Skipped 439 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

```
package com.example.hp.classcircuit;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//decleare valiables
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
BluetoothDevice mDevice;
ListView listView;
ConnectThread mConnectThread;
ArrayList pdal;
String DEVICE_ADDRESS;
boolean found=false;
BluetoothManager BM;
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)//for chacking sutable 
 //API
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);//Listview in xml
    //call BT Manager
    BM= (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    //call BT Adaptor
    mBluetoothAdapter=BM.getAdapter();
    //call paired device
    pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        // Device does not support Bluetooth
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Device not support bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
   //check BT is on or off
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
        }

    pdal=new ArrayList();

    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            pdal.add(device.getName());

        }

        ArrayAdapter pda=new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,pdal);

        listView.setAdapter(pda);
    }
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(myListClickListener);


}
```

**

> //action click listnor for listview

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener myListClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        String DeviceName=pdal.get(i).toString();
        for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
        {
            if(device.getName().equals(DeviceName)) {

                DEVICE_ADDRESS=device.getAddress();
                Log.i(device.getName(), DEVICE_ADDRESS);

                mDevice=device;

                found=true;

                break;
            }
        }
        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(mDevice);
        //call the inner class method
        mConnectThread.doInBackground();
    }
};
```

> //inner class

```
public class ConnectThread extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long>  {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    private final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    //constructor of inner class
    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;
        try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

     //override the methode
    protected Long doInBackground(String... strings) {
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        try {
            mmSocket.connect();
            Log.i("Status","connected");
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) { }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    //function for close the socket
    public void close() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

}

> Above is my async class .i didn't findout mistake please guide me where mistake done.Advance thanks to all

Comment: why is that: `mConnectThread.doInBackground()`? read [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for more info of `AsyncTask`

Comment: it is for calling the inner class method

Comment: read [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for more info of `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 1):

Don't call

```
mConnectThread.doInBackground();
```

What you did just ruins the concept of `AsyncTask` and does all the work on the UI thread.

> **Threading rules**
>
> There are a few threading rules that must be followed for this class
>   to work properly:
>
> - The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is done automatically as of JELLY_BEAN.
> - The task instance must be created on the UI thread.
> - **execute(Params...)** must be invoked on the UI thread.
> - Do **not call** onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(Result), **doInBackground(Params...)**, onProgressUpdate(Progress...) **manually**.
> - The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)

`AsyncTask` must be called with `execute()`. So change the above line to:

```
mConnectThread.execute();
```

Please note the way you have defined the `ConnectThread` expects some `String` parameters - `extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long>`, however you never use such parameters in your code. These parameters can be passed as arguments in the `execute(String ... params)` method. It is better to change the signature to:

```
public class ConnectThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(Void... params) {
         //your code here
    }
}
```